# Linear Algebra: orientations of vector spaces (problem)

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an exercise from J.Munkres's *Analysis on Manifolds*:

Consider the vectors $\mathbf{a_i}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that:$$[\mathbf{a_1},\mathbf{a_2},\mathbf{a_3},\mathbf{a_4}]=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &0&1&1 \\ 1&0&1&1\\1&1&2&0\end{bmatrix}$$
Let $V$ the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by $\mathbf{a_1}$ and $\mathbf{a_2}$. Show that 1) $\mathbf{a_3}$ and $\mathbf{a_4}$ also span $V$, and that 2) the frames $(\mathbf{a_1},\mathbf{a_2})$ and $(\mathbf{a_3},\mathbf{a_4})$ belong to opposite orientation of $V$.
I'm having troubles showing part 2): J.Munkres gives the following definitions concerning *frames* and *orientations of vector spaces*: [Orientations of $n$-dimensional vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314679/orientations-of-n-dimensional-vector-spaces). Do those definitions apply in this problem?

Comment: Yes. $V$ is a 2-dimensional subspace, so you can write $\{a_3, a_4\}$ as linear combinations of $a_1, a_2$. Then it gives you a $2\times 2$ matrix. Its determinant tells you whether their orientations are the same or not.

Comment: What do you mean with "it gives you"?

Comment: Can you give me an answer :)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll only explain part 2.

$\{a_1,a_2\}$ forms a basis for $V$. I want to express $a_3, a_4$ as linear combination of the basis. $a_3=a_1+a_2$, $a_4=a_1-a_2$. Therefore, in the basis $\{a_1,a_2\}$, $a_3, a_4$ can be expressed in a component form: $(1,1), (1,-1)$.

Observe that $\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=-2$ is negative. By the definition of orientation, the frames $\{a_1, a_2\}$, $\{a_3, a_4\}$ have different orientation.

---

Well, if you like, you can do it in another way, without choosing basis. That is, think of the cross product. If $a_1 \times a_2$ has the same direction as $a_3\times a_4$, then they have the same orientation. If the cross products are in the same direction, then they are in the opposite direction.

Comment: Why is your procedure correct?

Comment: Basing on my book definitions how can I get your result?

Comment: You're talking about basis, my book does say nothing special about them

Comment: @user246428 Well, you can think of cross product instead if you don't want to use a basis.